# Apply tooltip to a set in Raphael not for each side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, raphael

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/s0wgc884/1/) which shows the tooltip on hovering the cube. The tooltip is invoked whenever I hover over each face wherein I want the hover to appear only once on the whole cube. I prefer if I could use the same plugin which I have used in the fiddle, in-case if it is not possible, other solutions are also welcome.

**JS**

```
(function () {
    var paper = Raphael("paper", "100%", "100%");
    var cube2 = paper.set();
    // animate the set
    var anim = Raphael.animation({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);


    // second cube
    cube2.push(
    paper.path("M190 200 L260 160 330 200 260 240 190 200"),
    paper.path("M260 240 L330 200 330 280 260 320 260 240"),
    paper.path("M260 240 L260 320 190 280 190 200 260 240"));

    cube2.transform("t0 -80").attr({
        stroke: "#000000",
        opacity: 0
    }).animate(anim.delay(500));

    // hover for set
    function getHoverHandler(setName, fill1, fill2, fill3, swidth) {
        return function () {
            setName[0].attr({
                fill: fill1,
                cursor: "pointer",
                    "stroke-width": swidth
            });
            setName[1].attr({
                fill: fill2,
                cursor: "pointer",
                    "stroke-width": swidth
            });
            setName[2].attr({
                fill: fill3,
                cursor: "pointer",
                    "stroke-width": swidth
            });
        };
    }
    cube2.hover(getHoverHandler(cube2, "#000000", "#1e1e1e", "#282828", 0), getHoverHandler(cube2, "none", "none", "none", 1));
    // function for easy class setting
    function setClass(cubename, attrname) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cubename[i].node.setAttribute("class", attrname);
        }
    }
    // func ends
    setClass(cube2, "secondcube");
    // calling tooltipster on each set
    $('.secondcube').tooltipster({
        content: "second cube",
        position: "left"
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I told you before I think you have two different solutions,  one with inline SVG and CSS and one with Rapahael and Javascript. I prefer the first one, but I will show you an example of both.

Inline Svg with CSS:

```
HTML:

<body>
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="cube">
<path id="f1" d="M190,200L260,160L330,200L260,240L190,200"></path>
<path id="f2" d="M260,240L330,200L330,280L260,320L260,240"></path>
<path id="f3" d="M260,240L260,320L190,280L190,200L260,240"></path>
</g>
</svg>
</body>

CSS:

svg {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
#cube {
    fill:white;
    stroke:black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#cube:hover #f1 {
    fill:black;
}
#cube:hover #f2 {
    fill:#1e1e1e;
}
#cube:hover #f3 {
    fill:#282828;
}

JQUERY:

$('#cube').tooltipster({
    content: "second cube",
    position: "left"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zd33x1et/

Raphael:

```
var R = Raphael("paper");
var coor = [[130,170],[270,90],[410,170],[410,330],[270,410],[130,330]];
var toolText = ["first cube", "second cube", "third cube", "fourth cube", "fifth cube", "sixth cube"];
var cube =[];
var ed = [];
var i = 0;
function ont(n) {
    cube[n].hover(function(){
        cube[n].attr({"fill-opacity":"1"})
    }, function(){
        cube[n].attr({"fill-opacity":"0"})
    });
};
for(i=0;i<coor.length;i++){
R.setStart();
R.path("M0,0l-70,-40 70,-40 70,40 -70,40").attr({fill:"#000"});
R.path("M0,0l70,-40 0,80-70,40 0,-80").attr({fill:"#1e1e1e"});
R.path("M0,0l0,80 -70,-40 0,-80 70,40").attr({fill:"#282828"});
ed[i] = R.path("M0,0l0,80 M0,0l70,-40 M0,0l-70,-40 0,80 70,40 70,-40 0,-80-70,-40-70,40");
ed[i].node.setAttribute("id","edges"+i);
cube[i] = R.setFinish();
cube[i].transform("t" + coor[i][0] + "," + coor[i][1]).attr({"fill-opacity":"0", "cursor": "pointer"});
ont(i);
$('#edges'+i).tooltipster({
    content: toolText[i],
    position: "left"
});
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77nfejnz/2/

Comment: you just wouldn't give up. Would u? :) I am accepting your answer (second one). IE support is the main aspect of this project and hence I have no other option than raphael. I will consider the other answer for future use.

Comment: crockz, Could you please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667004/translate-gradually-with-animate-an-svg-element-after-a-delay-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use following changes will give you output what you need.

```
(function () {
    var paper = Raphael("paper", "100%", "100%");
    var cube2 = paper.set();
    // animate the set
    var anim = Raphael.animation({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);


    // second cube
    cube2.push(
    paper.path("M190 200 L260 160 330 200 260 240 190 200"),
    paper.path("M260 240 L330 200 330 280 260 320 260 240"),
    paper.path("M260 240 L260 320 190 280 190 200 260 240"));

    cube2.transform("t0 -80").attr({
        stroke: "#000000",
        opacity: 0
    }).animate(anim.delay(500));

    // hover for set
    function getHoverHandler(setName, fill1, fill2, fill3, swidth) {
        return function () {
            setName[0].attr({
                fill: fill1,
                cursor: "pointer",
                    "stroke-width": swidth
            });
            setName[1].attr({
                fill: fill2,
                cursor: "pointer",
                    "stroke-width": swidth
            });
            setName[2].attr({
                fill: fill3,
                cursor: "pointer",
                    "stroke-width": swidth
            });
        };
    }
    cube2.hover(getHoverHandler(cube2, "#000000", "#1e1e1e", "#282828", 0), getHoverHandler(cube2, "none", "none", "none", 1));
    // function for easy class setting
    function setClass(cubename, attrname) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cubename[i].node.setAttribute("class", attrname + i);
        }
    }
    // func ends
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    setClass(cube2, "secondcube"+i);
    }

    // calling tooltipster on each set
    $('.secondcube30').tooltipster({
        content: "second cube",
        position: "left"
    });

})();
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/s0wgc884/2/)

Only upper part hover will show tooltip.

Comment: That is already achievable. I want the hover to be shown on hovering any side but only once, not just the upper part.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian means when you hover then show once.  then after again you hover then not show. like that?

Comment: Nope.. the hover behavior happens normally. Sorry to confuse you. The hover should work for all the face and not just for one.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian This is because hover effect is on diffrent part. one solution is You can give hover effect on svg. http://jsfiddle.net/s0wgc884/4/. Here svg area is big.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I knew that solution, but that is not feasible here. There is one more solution to this, which I am using right now. That makes use of custom created tooltip. I appreciate your help. Thank you. I will post it soon, if I don't get a proper solution meanwhile.