# Translate (gradually - with animate) an svg element after a delay using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, svg-animate

I have this cubes which I want to translate to a different X and Y point after a delay of say 3000. I am not able to understand how to do this with the help of jQuery. Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/3knd1xyw/). Below is the code.

**JS**

```
// code for fade in one by one
console.log("game begins");
allSVGs = $("g");
fadeIn(0);
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#cubeTop").animate({
        svgTransform: "translate(0, -160)"
    });
}, 3000);

function fadeIn(svgIndex) {
    console.log(svgIndex);
    allSVGs.eq(svgIndex).css({
        "display": "block",
            "opacity": "0"
    });
    allSVGs.eq(svgIndex).animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    }, {
        complete: function () {
            svgIndex++;
            if (svgIndex < allSVGs.length) //Making sure we don't exceed the maximum available SVG elements
            fadeIn(svgIndex); //Recursively calling the next elements animation (hide) from the completed one.
        },
        duration: 400
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**PS:** Sorry for not being clear. I just made an edit to the question.

Comment: Have your tried **[Velocity.js](http://codepen.io/sol0mka/pen/kzyjJ)**

Comment: I tried `Raphael.js` But I am facing some issue with it (hovering on a set). So I switched back to this. Now I am in not in liberty to change it again. Already wasted a lot of time switching back and forth. Is there any possible way to do it in SVG? If the answer is "NO", I would like that as an answer so that I can keep it as a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is possible. I just made some changes to your `setTimeOut`. Check if this is what you want:

```
setTimeout(function () {
     $("#cubeTop")
    .animate(
      {"min-height": -140},
      {duration: 1000,
       step: function( top ){
           this.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0,"+top+")");
         }
       });
}, 3000);
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3knd1xyw/3/)**

Comment: almost there (dancing).. But it moves down a little before it goes up. Any way to move it from where it already is?

Comment: Is this a good one? http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/3knd1xyw/4/ (I mean the code), And can I use this same method to other ID's as well? To spread them out?

Comment: Yep!! That's perfect!! but if you are speading other div's to some other direction say `left` or `right` then there might be slight change in code... :)

Comment: Oh! :( That's bad new. I had a function ready in my mind :P I will give it a try. I hope I can count on you again if that doesn't work. :D

Comment: Sure.. Anytime buddy.. :)

Comment: I am getting confused now. Can you help with the one for right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75363/discussion-between-guruprasad-rao-and-thomas-sebastian).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
$("#cubeTop").attr({
    transform:'translate(0,-140)'
})
```

```js
// code for fade in one by one
console.log("game begins");
allSVGs = $("g");
fadeIn(0);
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#cubeTop").attr({
        transform:'translate(0,-140)'
    })
}, 3000);

function fadeIn(svgIndex) {
    console.log(svgIndex);
    allSVGs.eq(svgIndex).css({
        "display": "block",
            "opacity": "0"
    });
    allSVGs.eq(svgIndex).animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    }, {
        complete: function () {
            svgIndex++;
            if (svgIndex < allSVGs.length) //Making sure we don't exceed the maximum available SVG elements
            fadeIn(svgIndex); //Recursively calling the next elements animation (hide) from the completed one.
        },
        duration: 400
    });
}
```

```css
svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#cube {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
#cubeTop {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
#cubeTopRight {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
#cubeTopRightDown {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
#cubeDown {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
#cubeLeftDown {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
#cubeLeft {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="cube">
        <path id="f1" d="M190,200L260,160L330,200L260,240L190,200"></path>
        <path id="f2" d="M260,240L330,200L330,280L260,320L260,240"></path>
        <path id="f3" d="M260,240L260,320L190,280L190,200L260,240"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="cubeTop" transform="translate(0, -80)">
        <path id="t1" d="M190,200L260,160L330,200L260,240L190,200"></path>
        <path id="t2" d="M260,240L330,200L330,280L260,320L260,240"></path>
        <path id="t3" d="M260,240L260,320L190,280L190,200L260,240"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="cubeTopRight" transform="translate(70, -40)">
        <path id="r1" d="M190,200L260,160L330,200L260,240L190,200"></path>
        <path id="r2" d="M260,240L330,200L330,280L260,320L260,240"></path>
        <path id="r3" d="M260,240L260,320L190,280L190,200L260,240"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="cubeTopRightDown" transform="translate(70, 40)">
        <path id="rd1" d="M190,200L260,160L330,200L260,240L190,200"></path>
        <path id="rd2" d="M260,240L330,200L330,280L260,320L260,240"></path>
        <path id="rd3" d="M260,240L260,320L190,280L190,200L260,240"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="cubeDown" transform="translate(0, 80)">
        <path id="cd1" d="M190,200L260,160L330,200L260,240L190,200"></path>
        <path id="cd2" d="M260,240L330,200L330,280L260,320L260,240"></path>
        <path id="cd3" d="M260,240L260,320L190,280L190,200L260,240"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="cubeLeftDown" transform="translate(-70, 40)">
        <path id="ld1" d="M190,200L260,160L330,200L260,240L190,200"></path>
        <path id="ld2" d="M260,240L330,200L330,280L260,320L260,240"></path>
        <path id="ld3" d="M260,240L260,320L190,280L190,200L260,240"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="cubeLeft" transform="translate(-70, -40)">
        <path id="l1" d="M190,200L260,160L330,200L260,240L190,200"></path>
        <path id="l2" d="M260,240L330,200L330,280L260,320L260,240"></path>
        <path id="l3" d="M260,240L260,320L190,280L190,200L260,240"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: But I want it to translate slowly not instantly. Can I use it with animate?

Comment: @ThomasSebastian i will try it's just that you didn't give any timing to the animation

Answer (score 0):

Add all the stuff in setTimeout function and try.

```
// code for fade in one by one
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("game begins");
    allSVGs = $("g");
    fadeIn(0);

    $("#cubeTop").animate({
        svgTransform: "translate(0, -160)"
    });


    function fadeIn(svgIndex) {
        console.log(svgIndex);
        allSVGs.eq(svgIndex).css({
            "display": "block",
            "opacity": "0"
        });
        allSVGs.eq(svgIndex).animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, {
            complete: function() {
                svgIndex++;
                if (svgIndex < allSVGs.length) //Making sure we don't exceed the maximum available SVG elements
                    fadeIn(svgIndex); //Recursively calling the next elements animation (hide) from the completed one.
            },
            duration: 400
        });
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: No! This is not what I want. This will animate everything after 3 seconds. I only want the `cubeTop` to animate ofter 3 seconds. And that `svgTransform` doesn't work as well.